# ios : subview of a button not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

My code is as follows:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(50, 125, 220, 40);
button.frame = frame;
button.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor  colorWithRed:0.42 green:0.66 blue:0.31 alpha:1.0];
button.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[self.view addSubview:button];
button.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
button.clipsToBounds = YES;

UILabel *addLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, 100, 100)];
addLabel.text = @"+";
addLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
addLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
addLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:80.0f];
[button addSubview:addLabel];
addLabel.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
addLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

My `button` is showing up fine in iOS/iPhone simulator, however `addLabel` label is not showing up at all.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame on your label is too large. The label text is being drawn outside the frame of your button as a result. Ideally, the frame of your label would be *at most* as tall as the button height.

Comment: This is the right answer. Since UILabel centers vertically and you have centering horizontally, the text will appear approximately {65.0f, 65.0f} from the top left of the image, but your image is only 40px tall.

Answer (score 0):

Well UIButton already has a titleLabel. Have you tried just using that instead?

```
button.titleLabel.text = "+";
```

or even using a different button type:

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
```